# Ckeditor - На сайте показывает html-код вместо текста

Tags: ckeditor

В админке все нормально, а на сайте показывает код, как в Источнике. Как исправить?

Вот:

[image]

Comment: @maxim123123123, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Очень похоже на htmlspecialchars. Перед вставкой следует делать htmlspecialchars_decode(). Если мы говорим о php, конечно.

Если в общем - у вас html-код преобразуется в текст. Надо декодировать обратно.